# Add class to one <i> tag with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to find answer to my issue, but I am pretty sure that I am asking google a wrong question.
I have such code:

```
<div class="icons">
  <i class="fas fa-sun iconDisp active-icon"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud iconDisp"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-sun-rain iconDisp "></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon iconDisp"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy iconDisp "></i>
</div>
```

Now my problem is that i want to display only one icon with class active. I was trying to do this with 
"if" and DOM manipulation, but my results have been very poor, every time class was added to all itmes that do not have class active.

So I have tried something like this:

```
const iconsLoader = document.querySelectorAll('.iconDisp');

const activeIcon = function (){
  if(!iconsLoader.classList.contains('active')) {
    iconsLoader.classList.add('active')
  } 
}
```

Maybe in activeIcon should be a loop that goes through all  tags or something

Comment: Could you show us your attempt to see what you tried?

Comment: Which element do you want to add it to? And why setTimeout?

Comment: <i> tags and setTimeout as a i want it to some sort of animated thing that displays one icon at the time

Comment: they added to all because you selecting all `querySelectorAll('.iconDisp')`

Answer (score 0):

First hide, all your icons, then manually add `active-icon` class to one of them.

```css
.iconDisp { display: none; }
.active-icon { display: block; }
```

In your JavaScript, you will have to add an event listener to each icon in order to change the active-tab on click. Inside this listener, you check that the current click is NOT the active tab, if its not the active tab then you remove the `active-icon` class from the currently active and change it to the new active icon. Something like so:

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icons i');
icons.forEach((icon) => {
  icon.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if(!icon.classList.contains('active-icon') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const currentActiveIcon = document.querySelector('.active-icon');
        currentActiveIcon.classList.remove('active-icon');
        icon.classList.add('active-icon');
      }, 1000); // happens after 1 second
    }
  })
})
```

This code is untested and written from memory, but should work.

Comment: thanks for that, you pushed mi in a right direction

Answer (score -2):

**This code might help you.**

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll('.iconDisp');

function removeClass() {
  Array.from(icons).map(icon=>{
    icon.classList.remove("active-icon");
});
}

Array.from(icons).map(icon=>{
    icon.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
    removeClass();
    e.target.classList.add("active-icon");
    },500);
  })
});
```

```css
i.iconDisp {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  color: black;
  font-size:12px;
} 
i.iconDisp.active-icon {
  color: red;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="icons">
  <i class="fas fa-sun iconDisp"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud iconDisp"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-sun-rain iconDisp "></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-moon iconDisp"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-cloud-showers-heavy iconDisp "></i>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you change it?